# How can I open a .dll with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, dll

I'm a moderately experienced Unity programmer, but I haven't explored much of Visual Studio outside of writing scripts. I've just joined a team where a programmer has been building a toolkit using a series of .dlls, but upon attempting to open them in Visual Studio, I'm just getting a directory tree on a white background.

[image]

Can anybody suggest how I can open this .dll? From what I can tell from the Unity Project view, there should be a bunch of relevant scripts available within... but all I can seem to access is this white screen.

Any advice would be very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DLL is compiled code.  To "open" it you [add a reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(VS.ReferenceManager)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.7)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2022). You can also examine its contents using [ILSpy](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/ilspy/9MXFBKFVSQ13?hl=en-us&gl=us).